# How to Find The Earliest Date in Each Month From a List?

Tags: c#

Consider the following list:

```
15/5/2017,
3/5/2017,
7/4/2017,
4/4/2017,
1/4/2017,
31/3/2017,
22/3/2017,
5/3/2017,
2/3/2017
```

We expect the output to be:

```
3/5/2017,
1/4/2017,
2/3/2017
```

I tried

```
        List<StockValue> monthlyStocks = new List<StockValue>();
        List<StockValue> MonthlyFirstStock = new List<StockValue>();
        foreach(StockValue st in data)
        {
            if(monthlyStocks.Count > 0)
            {
                if(st.Date.Month != monthlyStocks.Last().Date.Month)
                {
                    MonthlyFirstStock.Add(monthlyStocks.OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
                    monthlyStocks = new List<StockValue>();
                }
            }

            monthlyStocks.Add(st);
        }
        MonthlyFirstStock.Add(monthlyStocks.OrderBy(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: You have almost a 1.6 K rep...you should know that this is a poor question.  Where's your effort?  Show us what *you* have tried.  No one is writing the code for you. C'mon, you've been a member for almost 5 years here.  Are you letting someone borrow your account?

Answer (score 2):

Explanation in comments.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 5, 15));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 5, 3));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 4, 7));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 4, 4));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 4, 1));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 3, 31));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 3, 22));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 3, 5));
        dates.Add(new DateTime(2017, 3, 2));

        var firstOfEachMonths = dates
            // Group the dates by their month.
            .GroupBy(date => date.Month)
            // Project each group into the earliest day.
            .Select(group => group
                    .OrderBy(date => date.Day)
                    .First())
            .ToList();

        /* 
         * Output:
         * 03.05.2017 00:00:00
         * 01.04.2017 00:00:00
         * 02.03.2017 00:00:00
         */
        foreach (var firstOfEachMonth in firstOfEachMonths) 
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(firstOfEachMonth);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq and lambda expressions:

```
var lstFirstDayOfMonth = lstDate.GroupBy(d => d.Month).Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Day).First()).ToList();
```